# Symfony adding EventListener in a closure and getting NULL

Tags: php, forms, exception, symfony, event-listener

I'm getting error "Call to a member function getAgent() on a non-object".

Here is my code in AgentsType.php:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('agents', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'MyBundle:agents',
            'property' => 'name',));

    $formModifier = function(FormInterface $form, agents $agent) {
        $description = $agent->getDescription();
        $form->add('description', 'text');
    };

    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
        function(FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            $data = $event->getData(); //ERROR HERE, returns NULL
            $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getAgent()); // Exception HERE
        }
    );

    $builder->get('agents')->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function(FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            $agent = $event->getForm()->getData();
            $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $agent);
        }
    );
}
```

$event->getData(); is NULL, I var_dumped $event and it's a very big amount of objects.

The purpose is to generate the form dynamically after choosing an agent entity in a select field, in this case a description field.

Can anyone advice me what to do with this error or why is getData() = NULL??

EDIT:

The main purpose of this is that the user can add/disable/update Agents. The main idea is to show just a select or dropdown field and an "Add Agent" button. If the user selects one name from the select field, then is the form for the Agents Entity filled with its data. That's the reason to have an EventListener, to detect any selection in the select field, and then show the data according to the user selection. Hope this clarifies a bit the goal.

Comment: I'm not sure, but is there any data at the "PRE_SET_DATA" event? So is there any result when calling `getData()`?

Comment: I'm following this docu http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html, and I've seen more examples and they implement the PRE_SET_DATA event like that. It should be data there.

Comment: Oh I got what the event is used for. Did you set any initial data in your controller, where you instantiate the form?

Comment: yes, there's a findAll() method there being called:

        $form = $this->createForm(new AgentsType());

        return $this->render('MyBundle:agents:agents.html.twig', array(
            'entities' => $entities,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));

I'm showing the 2 entities name found with that method in an Entity Field Type, but ya, maybe that's not the way to do it. I'm really stacked with that.

Comment: `findAll()` will return an array of the found objects. if you pass the result of `findAll()` to the form creation (like: `$this->createForm(new AgentsType(), $findAllResult);` there will also be this exception. The correct way would be: `$this->createForm(new AgentType(), $singleAgentObject);`. Also in the way you wrote it (`$this->createForm(new AgentType());`) there will be no data, so `->getData()` will return null.

Comment: If I return the form with an entity, now I get this error:
'Neither the property "agents" nor one of the methods "getAgents()", "isAgents()", "hasAgents()", "__get()" or "__call()" exist and have public access'

Comment: OK, I think you have more a problem of structure. What should the form type be for? Create a single Agent, (multi-)select Agents?

Comment: I think I better update the question and I explain it a bit more. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sure, I'll try to answer as soon as you finished editing.

Comment: OK, I got it a bit more. So you want a dropdown containing all agents and after selection of one, there should be a form displayed to edit the agent?

Comment: Yes, that's the goal.

Comment: It may be more easy to have a form field of type "choice" with an onselect handler to handle selection and form rendering via JavaScript.

Comment: That means that the onselect handler can return the entity to the template and handle it with js? Can you paste here some docs or tutos for the onselect handler? Even make it an answer and I'll check it out, if it works I'll accept it :) Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a form type to display all agents.

```
// AgentsType.php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
  $builder
    ->add('agents', 'entity', array(
       'class' => 'MyBundle:Agent',
       'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $rep) {
         // some query for agents
       };
       'attr' => array('onselect' => 'loadAgentForm(this);')
     )
  );
}
```

And you will need some javascript to do an asynchronous call to another controller that returns a page, containing the AgentType form (not AgentsType).

```
function loadAgentForm(sender) {
  // if you use jquery:
  $("div#form-container").load(
    ("http://myurl.com/agent/editform?id=" + sender.value)
  );
}
```

If there are any remaining questions feel free to ask!!!

Comment: hi Benny, choice field doesn't have any query_builder option!

Comment: hi sry, misspelled. should be entity type.

Comment: The select has the onselect there, that's perfect, but the javascript function is not being called after selecting something. If I execute the little code directly in the console browser it works. The loadAgentForm function it's placed in my base javascript file, where my other functions are working properly.

Comment: Ok, it works with "onchange" :) If everything works fine I'll accept your question, you saved my life :) Vielen Dank Herr @Benny.